# Infinityfree laravel storage:link

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, storage, infinitifree

На моём локалхосте я сделал приложение на laravel. В нем можно загружать файлы, которые должны сохранятся. использовал storage для этого и `storage:link`, чтобы получить доступ к ним.

Я выложил проект на хостинг infinityfree. Но на нём нельзя использовать консоль\терминал. Я пробовал использовать роуты, но мне выдавало ошибку `symlink() has been disabled for security reasons`.

```js
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

Структура проекта такая[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ТО есть папки public как таковой нет, файлы из public лежат в корне.
Вот filesystem.php

```js
<< ? php

return [

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Filesystem Disk
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
  | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
  | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
  |
  */

  'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
  | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
  | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
  |
  */

  'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Filesystem Disks
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
  | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
  | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
  |
  | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
  |
  */

  'disks' => [

    'local' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
      'url' => env('APP_URL').
      '/storage',
      'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
      'driver' => 's3',
      'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
      'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
      'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
      'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

  ],

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Symbolic Links
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
  | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
  | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
  |
  */

  'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
  ],

];
```

Вот так я загружаю файлы

```js
$request - > file('image') - > store('birds');
```

Comment: Загрузите сразу в `public`. Или скопируйте с помощью PHP, Или отдавайте как Base64 через `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Вы с такими вопросами лучше в техподдержку хостинга обратитесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом тыка определил куда ведет base_path - в моём случае в директорию laravel.
Напомню у меня такая структура, что в корне файлы из public, так же там директория laravel, в ней уже все файлы laravel.

в дисках public изменил root на `base_path('../storage')`, что указывает на директорию storage в моем корне.
То же самое в links

```js
'disks' => [
  'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => base_path('../storage'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').
    '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
  ],
],

'links' => [
  base_path('../storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Надеюсь, я кому-то помог